# How to slice a 2D array from another 2D array and get the rest

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

I have a numpy array `A = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],[1, 0, 1, 1, 1]])`

I want to slice `B = np.array([[0, 1, 0],[0, 0, 1],[1, 0, 1]])` from A and get the rest of A as 
a numpy array which is `C = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 0],[1,1]])`

I am looking for a general code as my matrix B changes at different iterations inside A.

Thanks

Comment: What can you say about B more generally? For example, is it always the left side, or corner, or do you have to search?

Comment: in my problem, I have array A which has a fixed number of columns. but the number of rows changes at each iteration of my main code. I just gave an example of A which here is 3*5.  The place of B changes without any pattern. sometimes it is in the right side, sometimes in the left, or in the middle. But the shape of B is constant. it is always 3*3

Comment: I am not looking to generate a code for B. I already have it. I want a general code that looks inside A and give the rest of columns as a new variable.

Comment: Wondered to know if there is a way to use np.delete() to take out B from A.

Comment: np.delete` returns a new array.  It does not work in-place.  Also the delete specification is by index, not 'value'

Comment: Sounds like the first question is finding the columns or rows?) of `A` that match `B`.  Is the dtype alwys integer?

Comment: yes, it is integer. B is always a sub array of A. but the place of it changes. it can be either on the left or middle or right. I want to remove that part of A and get the remaining part of A. for example of B is on the middle of A (column 1:3 of A) I want to get that part of A which is column 0 and 4

Comment: Do you know what columns of A represent B?  Or are you looking for them?

Comment: If it's middle `C=np.concatenate([A[:,[0]], A[:,[4]]],axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

In numpy, it is actually quite easy, like what you can do for this problem is this:

```
import numpy as np
k = 3 #k is used to slice the array, here k = 3
A = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],[1, 0, 1, 1, 1]])
C = np.array([a[-i:] for i in range(k, len(a)])
A = np.array([a[i:i+k] for i in range(0, len(a), k)])
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually, I have my B array at different iterations of main code that I didnt put here, and I dont want to create a new B. I want to get C which is the rest of A by deleting B from it.  At some iterations in my main code, B sometimes is for example first 3 columns of A, some times it is in the middle, etc.

Comment: Hey @PeymanBahrami I guess I have changed what you wanted, according to the code above, now you will have only one new array `C` and then `A` is modified.

Comment: You can slice the whole array, no iteration.  `B=A[:, :3]`, C=A[:, 3:]`

Comment: no, I mean, I have a main code and B varies in the code.